# how to implement "Automatically grant access when new devices are added"

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am checking the device access API.

There is a API of device access in SoftLayer_User_Customer.

but I can't find a API of "Automatically grant access when new devices are added".

where can I find that? or SoftLayer doesn't suppot that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add permission to implement Automatically grant access when new device are added.

This is the rest api to add permission:

```
POST 
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[userId]/addPortalPermission
```

Body: Json

```
{

"parameters": [
                 {
                     "keyName": "ACCESS_ALL_HARDWARE"  // To add the “ACCESS_ALL_GUEST” and “ACCESS_ALL_DEDICATEDHOSTS”  permissions you have to run the same request, changing                              
                 }                                    //  only the “keyName”.                                                                                                      
            ] 
}
```

To get the “keyName” of all the permission,  use the following rest api:

```
GET 
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission/getAllObjects
```

To verify that the permission were added, use this rest api:

```
GET 
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[userId]/getPermissions
```